# How can a component do layout of its children?

Tags: reactjs

I've been playing with React for a couple of weeks, so I'm far from an expert. This is the problem: I'm building some components that layout their children. That is, a`Layout`may be used as in:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <...child 1/>
                <...child 2/>
                ...
            </Layout>
        );
    }
});
```

Well, Layout does not own the children, so it cannot modify their props. It cannot clone the children either, as they could contain refs. Could Layout wrap each child in a (properly positioned) div? Would a child with a ref result in the correct update of SomeComponent refs? Is there a better way of doing this?

I thought a bit more about the general problem of parent-child communication and I'm more confused than before. The documentation states:

> "For parent-child communication, simply pass props."

In a related part of the documentation we find:

> "In React, an owner is the component that sets the props of other components."

So, what gives? It seems to me that **only the owner, not the parent, can set props**.

This has been discussed here in several posts, but I find no satisfactory answer. Some answers suggest cloning the children in the parent, but we run into problems if the original owner set ref props in its "ownees". In the example above, SomeComponent owns the components passed to Layout as children. If I clone the children in Layout (say, to add a callback) the layout becomes the owner of the clones so SomeComponent refs will not get them.

I am utterly confused.

Comment: Can you please provide more context?  It's unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: In a nutshell, I want to pass props (a callback) to my children. Without cloning them, because that will break the refs mechanism.

Comment: Okay, but what is your actual goal?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Why can't you pass the callback as a prop when you do `<component>`?

Comment: What do you mean "when I do <component>"?

Comment: He means why can't the callback be a prop passed from your parent rather than your `<Layout />` component?  If you let us know what you're trying to accomplish by this that can't be done by just passing a prop, we can better help you.

Comment: Because the Layout parent (the owner of Layout's children) does not know anything about Layout and what it needs. Layout needs to be notified of certain changes in its children.

Comment: I'll try to be more clear. Layout positions its children according to some Layout policies and the sizes of its children. Layout assumes that its children may change sizes for various reasons. It just wants - if possible - to be told. So it would like to provide its children - created SomeComponent - with a callback to say so. Mind you, SomeComponent cannot provide such callback. It knows nothing of Layout's needs, nor does it care. It just uses Layout, well, for layout purposes.

Comment: where it says "created SomeComponent" it should say "created by SomeComponent"

Comment: Why does Layout need/want to know when the size of one of its children changes? That's a valid question. Thing is, the combination of various Layouts describes a tree. It would be possible for any Layout node to simply recompute the size of all its children every time it needs to layout them. However, most of it's children do not change sizes, so I though it would be more efficient to let each child cache its size. A child changing size would invalidate the caches of its parent, its parent parent, etc, all the way to the root. Most nodes would not need to be recomputed, though.

Comment: Now, you can tell me "Man, that's information flowing upwards, ReactJS is all about the opposite direction" and I will have to agree with that. Still, the problem seems real enough. In a tree of depth n, the updates that I would like to have are O(n). The alternative (recompute the size of everything) with depth n and branching factor m is O(n^m). For even small n and m, that's huge.

Comment: By passing a callback, you want your component to essentially to have and know about two parents because it needs to know to call the callback of its parent but also belong to its owner (and preserve its `ref` to it). That breaks the basic agreement that a node has a single parent. You cannot preserve `ref` across cloning (https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5d3b12bb3bd6a092cf00ede07b8255a8399c2e58/src/utils/cloneWithProps.js#L36) like you said.

Comment: ssorallen: According to the documentation, Layout is the parent of <child 1> and SomeComponent is its pwner (and great*grandparent) so, no, that does not break any agreement I was aware of, nor does it turn the virtual DOM into a more general graph than a tree. I'm not talking about <child 1> keeping a reference to Layout, I'm talking about receiving information from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking, but there are things that a wrapping component like your `<Layout />` can do to children.

You mention you'd like to wrap each child component in a div.  Here's an example of that:

```
var Layout = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var children = [];
        if (this.props.children) {
            for (var i=0; i < this.props.children.length; i++) {
                var child = this.props.children[i];
                children.push(
                    <div className="child-container">
                        {child}
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="layout-container">
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Above you can see that you can access the children of `Layout` in `this.props.children` which is just an array of child components.  So by using a simple for loop as above, or using `this.props.children.map` you can wrap each child however you like and render it.

Comment: Yes, that will work and will not break the refs mechanism. However, I cannot pass a callback to my children.

Comment: this.props.children isn't an array, it's an opaque data structure, see [React.Children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children); it's sometimes an array but that's an implementation detail and shouldn't be relied upon