# Create React element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, chat

I'm doing a Chat with ReactJS (kinda Facebook), and I created the ChatBox with ReactJS, so whenever you click on an online user a ChatBox has to be created, my question is, Is there anyway to create a ReactJS component dynamically maybe adding the ChatBox to a div or to another React element?

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/victorcastillo/2c6cb3af4650729eaa1f

Comment: So when you click on a name you render a new chat box?

Comment: @limelights The problem is that if I render a new ChatBox the previous ones will disappear

Comment: Simplest way would be for your container to keep a list of chatboxes and just append a new chatbox. http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/12132/

Comment: @limelights I never thought about it!! Please write that down as an answer!

Comment: A bit off topic, but in jsx you should use className instead of class:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/346

Comment: @DBrowne I know, but thank you I didn't notice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way would be to have your container store a list of chatboxes to which you append or remove chatboxes depending if they are open or closed.

```
var ChatBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div>a new chatbox!</div>;
    }
});

var Container = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { chatboxes: [] };
    },
    renderChatbox: function () {
        var cbs = this.state.chatboxes;
        cbs.push(<ChatBox />);
        this.setState({chatboxes: cbs});
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello, do you want to open a chatbox <a onClick={this.renderChatbox}>click here</a>
        {this.state.chatboxes}
        </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Container name="World" />, document.body);
```

Expanding on the answer a bit and assuming that you're not using the Flux pattern then in order for the container to know that a ChatBox has been closed you would have to pass a callback from the container to each ChatBox.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer,  you are right, I'm not using the Flux pattern, by the way, have you ever implemented Flux with Django?

Comment: Yes. Is there anything you need help with?

Comment: If you have an example about Flux with Django would be very interesting to share :D

Comment: I have one with flask, but it's the same principle behind it. https://github.com/limelights/todo-reflux . Instead of decorating each function you would just put the urls in `urls.py` and point that to your function/cbv.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 3):

> so whenever you click on an online user a ChatBox has to be created

When the user clicks on an online-user-glyph this should trigger a state change -- you'll be keeping track of open chat windows.  The state change will trigger a `React.render` cycle.  In your render function you'll have to decide how and where to invoke and place your chat windows, based on how many open ones there are (state variables).  These should be React components in their own right, and you'll pass/inject functions and Id's as props into them.

That's the answer without code example.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. To a div, you just do the usual

```
React.render(
    <ChatBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

You can pass a react class definition (i.e. the ChatBox variable) or a [react factory](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html) in a property. You can later generate an instance of that component and add it somewhere in your view. The easiest way to add it to the view is to change the [children of a Container type of component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317844/how-can-a-component-do-layout-of-its-children).

Example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/widged/pen/KdwLba) (es6 syntax)